# How to change the path when compile the bootstrap compass file

Tags: css, gruntjs, compass-sass, angular-ui-bootstrap, grunt-contrib-compass

I've added bootstrap-sass into my project and import it to my application.scss file like this

@

```
import "../bower_components/bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/_bootstrap-compass";

.bootstrap{
  @import "../bower_components/bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/_bootstrap";
}
```

In the bootstrap compass file, there are functions

```
@function twbs-font-path($path) {
  @return font-url($path, true);
}

@function twbs-image-path($path) {
  @return image-url($path, true);
}
```

Which will be used to set the paths for images and fonts.

After I build the css file using compass, the output of the css file contains the following paths to the font files

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
    src: url(/.tmp/styles/fonts/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot);
    src: url(/.tmp/styles/fonts/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot?#iefix) format("embedded-opentype"), url(/.tmp/styles/fonts/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff) format("woff"), url(/.tmp/styles/fonts/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf) format("truetype"), url(/.tmp/styles/fonts/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg#glyphicons_halflingsregular) format("svg");
}
```

How can I change it so that the source path to become:

```
src: url(./fonts/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot)
```

instead of src: `url(/.tmp/styles/fonts/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot)`

Please note that the application.scss was built by **grunt-contrib-compass**

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to change your compass configuration and set the fonts_dir to be 'fonts' instead of (as it seems) '.tmp/styles/fonts'.

Comment: Hi there, where can I specify the @font directory when I import the files? I don't want to change it directly inside the bower component. Thanks